# How will send a request for 'course creator' role to admin in moodle?

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

In my moodle site admin can add a user as course creator. But how will newly joined user will inform admin that they want the role 'course creator'. How will send such a request to admin. Please give a solution or suggest a plugin. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution to your question is probably [Course requests](https://docs.moodle.org/35/en/Adding_a_new_course#Course_requests)

Under admin check the http://YOURMOODLE/admin/settings.php?section=courserequest page